# Is it possible for an iOS app that runs on MacOS as "Designed for iPad" to have a different name when installed on MacOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

Let's say I have an app called 'FooBar'.

in my current *info.plist* file I have an entry 'Bundle display name' = 'FooBar' - which I belive causes the app name to be 'FooBar' when it is installed.

On MacOS however it appears there is another Mac Application that has the same name. And since the app is being installed into the Applications folder on Mac there are naming conflicts, which are tricky to deal with for the end customer - and unfortunately many of my customers seem to use the other 'FooBar' app already.

Is there is any way I can change the name of the iOS app to 'Foo' - but just when it is installed on Mac via 'designed for iPad' and leave the name at 'FooBar' for iPadOS and iOS?

Comment: Sounds like the issue has nothing to do with the display name. The issue is with the name of the .app that's created.